# C++: Media Player using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to develop a media player using Qt. On the basis of the documentation I have done the following things:

**pro file**

```
QT       += core gui multimedia
QT += multimediawidgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Player
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**main.cpp file**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets/QVideoWidget>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlaylist>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlayer *player=new QMediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget *videowidget=new QVideoWidget;
    QMediaPlaylist *playlist=new QMediaPlaylist;
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/VideoLAN/VLC/stram.mp4"));
    player->setVideoOutput(videowidget);

    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    player->play();
    videowidget->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

As for the header file I have included **mainwindow.h**

**EDIT**

All the erorrs are gone but now the output which is coming is:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zY1vLEk8B9c" is  HTTP page, not a media file, you need to get link to the media file first, pages as [savefrom](http://en.savefrom.net) some how are able to do this.

Comment: So I need the embed link? Or some video file that I have in my computer?

Comment: @Arpegius I edited it, now it plays a video that I have stores in VLC folder, still does not work. And I tried the other backslash too, does not work.

Comment: Try with absolute path. The link that savefrom provied me work fine.

Comment: @Arpegius How to find the path? I pasted the link there, then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add this string to .pro file:

```
QT += multimediawidgets
```

for additional info: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvideowidget.html

Comment: No change. I did add and yes I have checked the page, already tried adding multimedia widgets but to no avail.

Comment: Do you make clean, run qmake, build again? It's work (compiled succesfully) for me after adding "multimediawidgets" library in .pro file.

Comment: I am on windows, so how to do it? And I did clean all and rebuild all. No joy.

And how to add the library, if you are asking about adding it to the pro file, then yes I have added.

Comment: Are you using QtCreator?

Comment: My version is 2.8.2 and after right mouse click on project appears context menu. With commands "clean", "run qmake", "rebuild" and many more.

Comment: Ah, did it. I have 15 left, wait shall edit the question and post again. Thanks :)